# Round corners for a shape with tiled background

Tags: android

I need to create a View with rounded corners which uses a tiled image background. I've tried `layer-list` already but this doesn't work for me because `bitmap` is just placed on top of `shape` with rounded corners. Please advice.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="12dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
                android:topRightRadius="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/profile_data_background_im"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/. http://ruibm.com/?p=184

Comment: Did you tried to swap items in your layer-list?

Comment: @Dmitry yes I tried to swap them but no success

Comment: @Raghunandan, this is about simple image, but I need a tiled image

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at library [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/makeramen/RoundedImageView) on github, might be just what you are looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to use this RoundedImageView as a background for let's say LinearLayout?

Comment: You can scale the image to be fill parent in your LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageView` instead - it has ability to draw two different drawables (one as `background`, and one as `src`).

Set your tiled bitmap as a `background`. Set yout rounded square as a `src`

Comment: How then I can set it as background for any container, such as LinearLayout?

Comment: @siik in case of ViewGroup and other subclasses - you can override `dispatchDraw` method and draw your backgroud manually as two separate drawables.